# Go back to default state if nothing is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a results page with 2 columns: LEFT COLUMN contains a list of items that help the user filter his results. RIGHT COLUMN contains all the results.

By default, there are no items selected in the left column, hence, there are no results to show/filter on the right column. There are, however, some instructions that tell the visitor how to use the filters or items on the left column to see his results in the right column.

As of right now, I am capable of hiding the DIV that contains the results upon entering the page while having the instructions visible, and once the user clicks on an item in the left column, then hide the instructions and start showing the results.

My problem is that I don't know how to go back to the 'default' state if no items are selected. How do I show the instructions again once the user decides to clear all his filters?

Does this make sense? Let me know if you need me to explain more.

[**- Live Demo here -**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/CDkcB/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the count of links with active class and if the count is greater than 0 then hide the instructions else show it.

So you need to change the ready handler to:

```
$(function(){
    //
    $('#results').hide();

    //Buttons inside accordions
    $('.acitem a').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
                if($('.acitem a.active').length > 0){
                    $('#instructions').hide();
                    $('#results').fadeIn();
                }
                else{
                    $('#instructions').show();
                    $('#results').hide();

                }
});
```

Check this jsfiddlet.net: http://www.jsfiddle.net/CDkcB/6/

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot Cybernate. I did not know about the .length property.

Comment: Since I'm using "a href" tags, the browser jumps to the top on click, so I added 'return false' at the end of the function to prevent this. Demo is updated: http://www.jsfiddle.net/CDkcB/7/

Comment: You can use javascript:void(0) as the href attribute for the a href tags.

Comment: Cybernate, the problem with using javascript:void(0) is that is not SEO friendly. Now, the dummy links I'm using will be dynamically replaced by real URLs, hence, if the user wants to save or send the URL to someone, then the other person can see the same results the first user saw.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient way to do it, but the basic idea is to, every time a link is clicked, check and see how many "active" links there are:

```
$('.acitem a').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ($('.acitem .active').length) {
        $('#instructions').fadeOut();
        $('#results').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#results').fadeOut();
        $('#instructions').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: sdleihssirhc, your example worked as well. Gave you a vote. Thanks a lot.